# eonasdan bootstrap: unable to increase hours using hour arrow icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using [Eonasdan datetimepicker version : 4.17.47](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus) by importing [this JS file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qcGODvDfQsyzVXcSIMkNoC0TM9EtGnID/view?usp=sharing) in a project.

Also, I am using some custom validation to make sure that shows a red text when the user enters a time range different than expected. I am no setting `minDate` or `maxDate` because the time range is dynamic and can be changed.

Sometimes though, the user is unable to increment hours / minutes by clicking on the up arrow key. The `datetimepicker` is set to use for only time, thus initialized as:

```
$("#timePicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "LT",
        allowInputToggle: true,
        keepInvalid: true // the up arrow icon was not working, so I thought this will fix it but it didn't
      });
```

and the template:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 time-block">
   <div class="control input-group customtextInput" id="timePicker">
      <input type="text" id="stime" name="time" class="inputText col-md-12 form-control time-picker"
         data-bind="event:{ blur: function (data, event) {$parent.handleDateTimeOnblur.bind(data, $parent, event)() } }"
         required />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
         ...
      </span>
   </div>
   <p class="text-danger login-error-msg time-empty" id="time-error" aria-label="Error Message"
      data-bind="text: $parent.timeErrorMessage()" role="alert"></p>
</div>
```

You can see a demo [here](https://l7731499c1dev-store.occa.ocs.oraclecloud.com/relocation-pet)

I've noticed that when user tries to go to next date using the datetimepicker, it stops incrementing, (The date pickers on this given page are not connected, they are seperately initialized.)

Any help regarding this will be truly appreciated!!

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611566/knockout-bindinghandler-with-eonasdan-datepicker-does-not-fire-dp-change-event-w perhaps helps you.

Comment: Hey Jose, thanks for the reply do you think the time is not getting updated using arrow icons because `dp.change` is not getting fired? Though when I try to update time by clicking on numeric values of hours and minutes; then it works, but not with the arrow icons

Answer (score 0):

This issue us fixed now. See [Discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus/discussions/2375)